# Titanium : How to use a varibale getting form one .js file is to be user in to another .js file

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, cordova, titanium

I have implemented an app in **titanium**. I'm very new to titanium and **JavaScript..**

My requirement is as follows

I have table view with list of project names

I *need to add/append another project by tapping on Add button, which goes to another list of All projects.*

I need to select A project from list of **AllProjects in 2nd window (AllProjects.JS)** and pop to back to **1st window** (**CurrentProjects.JS**) with selected Project and append that selected project in hte currentList of projects.

I tried as follows

IN All Projects.js

```
$.table.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var selected = e.row;
    alert(e.row.title);
    var TodayStatus = new Alloy.createController("TodayStatus");
    TodayStatus.SELECTEDPROJECT = e.row.title;
    TodayStatus.getView().open();
});
```

I was unable to retrieve `SELECTEDPROJECT` to the `currentProjects.js` file

How to achieve it? Please help me.

How do I declare `SELECTEDPROJECT`,  where do I declare `SELECTEDPROJECT`, how use it, how to assign a value to it?

Comment: Duplicate.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187554/titanium-javascript-how-to-pass-data-values-from-one-window-to-another-window/18203015#18203015

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data by passing parameter like this.

```
x.addEVentListener('click', function(e){
    var controller = require('controllerPath').createWindow(e.value);
controller.open();
})
```

And in controller.js

```
exports.createWindow = function(value)
{
   //whatever You like to do with UI
}
```